# resize an UIImage and save it on my app file system

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimage, image-resizing

I need to resize an UIImage and save it on my app file system,

I can  [resize the image](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/)

or just show it with a smaller cgrect for the frame,

but how can i save this newly resized image on my app file sys?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your image is called image

```
//Where the 0 denotes the compression (0 to 1).
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyImageFolder"];

NSError *error;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder

NSString *fullPath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", imageName]]; //add our image to the path

bool successI = [imageData writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES];
if (successI) {
    //        NSLog(@"Image saved correctly");
} else
    NSLog(@"Error while saving Image");
```

Forgot to mention, you can change the

```
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

to save it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You can first convert the UIImage to NSData by

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation
```

or

```
UIImagePNGRepresentation
```

Then write the data to Document or Library folder in your app.