# Save image somewhere and use it in another ViewController (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I've written some code to make a screenshot of the view. I write that image to the photo library. But the thing is, I want to use that image in an other imageView in another ViewController. How can I save the image somewhere in the app and use it in another ViewController?

My code:

```
UIView* captureView = self.view;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(captureView.bounds.size, captureView.opaque, 0.0);
[captureView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 ,640,1136);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cropRect.size, captureView.opaque, 1.0f);
[screenshot drawInRect:cropRect];
UIImage * customScreenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(customScreenShot , nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628972/resize-an-uiimage-and-save-it-on-my-app-file-system

Comment: Are you using Storyboards? Do you need to save it, or will passing it to the other ViewController suffice?

Comment: using xib , i wanna pass it to another VC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to save your image on the disk:

```
NSString *documentDirectory = 
[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) 
                                                                        objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/myImage.png",documentDirectory];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(customScreenShot)];
[imageData writeToFile:pngFilePath atomically:YES];
```

And then you can create an UIImageView with the file:

```
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage 
imageWithContentsOfFile:pngFilePath]];
[self.view addSubview:myImageView];
```

Comment: where must i synthesize the imageDate??

Comment: You only synthesize for properties, in the case, imageData is not a property, it is a local variable. You can add the first part of my code right after yours, and then, in the other UIViewController you want to get the image, you use the second part, just add the documentDirectory and pngFilePath again to reference the image on disk.

Comment: its giving a error: "Use of undeclared identifier 'pngFilePaht'

Comment: O, i added DocumtDirectory and pngFilePath and it works!! thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Storyboards, you could pass it to the next view controller like so; in the prepareForSegue method ( this relieves you from having to save it to disk ):

Note:  the name of the segue is set by you in MainStoryboard.storyboard.  - `mySegue`.

`kMySegue` is just a key for that. i.e. `#define kMySegue @"mySegue"`

`imageInOtherViewController` is a UIImage in the other view controller.

```
// TheFirstViewController.m

    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    id destinationViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:kMySegue]){
        if ([destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setImageInOtherViewController:)]){
            [destinationViewController setImageInOtherViewController:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
            FastCameraViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
            viewController.delegate = self;
        }   
    } 


    // OtherViewController.h

    @interface OtherViewController : UIViewController 
    {
    }
    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *otherViewControllerImageView;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *imageInOtherViewController;

    // OtherViewController.m
    @implementation OtherViewController
    @synthesize otherViewControllerImageView;
    @synthesize imageInOtherViewController;

    - (void)viewDidLoad{
        [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        [[self otherViewControllerImageView] setImage:imageInOtherViewController];

   }
```

Comment: Sorry, but it xcode says that prepareForSegue is not declared?

Comment: You need to be using Storyboards.

Comment: I'm using xibs and i'm unable to use storyboard

Answer (score 0):

To cache your images I recommend using the [NSCache](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class first ie

```
NSCache* imagesCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
[imagesCache setName:@"imagesCache"];

[imagesCache setObject:customScreenShot forKey:@"image1"];
```

the good news is that `NSCache` accepts any object of type `id` so you can store images, mp3s, whatever you want.

If you would like to use the phone's file directory (which is more expensive to use than `NSCache`..) I recommend you use the `Library/Caches` directory instead of the `Documents` directory.. so building on iDevzilla's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16738374/766570):

```
NSString *documentDirectory =
[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)
 objectAtIndex:0];
```